# Using C++, How to detect process right before terminated

Tags: c++, windows, process

Im using Visual C++
I'm trying to monitor another process.
Is there a way to detect when the process is terminated ? I mean right before it's terminated, the program can raise an event. After that event, the process will be terminated.
I want my code run before the process is terminated.

The reason I want to do that because I use WMI to detect the process started. But some the process is ended too quickly, my code doesn't not run yet, but the process already ended.

Comment: are you in control (i.e. actually writing the code for) both processes ?

Comment: No I'm not in the control. This is another process outside my code

Comment: in that case I dont know how (or even if) you could make it send a signal near termination and actually wait for your code to run before it terminates. does your code have to run **before** termination of the other process or can it run right after ?

Comment: You could trace the process. Exiting is a system call, which should be traceable.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I really need to run before the termination. As you know, some process is very fast to run so the WMI can not catch it.

Comment: @KerrekSB : how can i trace for a system call ? do you mean I need to do hooking ?

Comment: There's no guarantee that your process gets to run between the start of the other program and its termination. If that all happens in a single uninterrupted timeslice, what would you do?

Answer (score 2):

You would use the `DebugActiveProcess` function, and then use a loop which starts with `WaitForDebugEvent` - when the process exits, you get a `EXIT_PROCESS_DEBUG_EVENT`.

You will probably get a bunch of other debug events [it depends on when you attach to the process and what the process does after that point]. For those, you will just issue a call to `ContinueDebugEvent` - if it was an exception, `DBG_EXCEPTION_NOT_HANDLED` should be used, otherwise, `DBG_CONTINUE`.

Once you see your `EXIT_PROCESS_DEBUG_EVENT`, you do your thing, then issue `DBG_CONTINUE`. You will also need to handle `LOAD_DLL_DEBUG_EVENT` by closing the handle given, or you'll leak handles.

I haven't used `DebugActiveProcess` in exactly this manner, but I believe this will work.

See these functions for more details:
[Windows Debugging Functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679303%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)